# JSP email sending error

Tags: java, jsp, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm creating a web application to send an email to some recipient. when I running this code I'm facing an exception like this

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /two.jsp at line 27

```
24:        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
25:        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
26: 
27:        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
28:                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
29:                      protected PasswordAuthentication  
30:                         getPasswordAuthentication() {
```

what should I do? this is my complete jsp code.

```
            <html>
            <body>

            <%@ page import="java.util.Properties" %>               
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.Message" %>
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.MessagingException" %>
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication" %>
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.Session" %>
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.Transport" %>
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress" %>
            <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>


            <%
            Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                protected PasswordAuthentication 
                                      getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                    return new PasswordAuthentication
                                      ("senderUsername","senderPassword");
                                }
                            });

                    try {

                        Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession );
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("senderemail@gmail.com"));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                InternetAddress.parse("recipient@gmail.com"));
                        message.setSubject("hi");
                        message.setText("text contrnt" +
                                "\n\n Test email");

                        Transport.send(message);

                        System.out.println("Done");

                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
            %>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Any help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,
                            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                protected PasswordAuthentication 
                                      getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                    return new PasswordAuthentication
                                      ("","");
                                }
                            });`

Use Session.getInstance() instead of Session.getDefaultInstance().

Comment: I have tried this. no error. code is compiling and running. but email not sent. what's the error?

Comment: I didn't get any error with the above code, I'm receiving emails.

Comment: when I running this code page will open in the browser and loading it without sendina an email. so what to do?

Comment: Can you see the "Done" string printed in console?

Comment: return new PasswordAuthentication
("myUsername","myPassword");

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myEmailAddress@gmail.com"));

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,                     InternetAddress.parse("recipient@gmail.com"));


I set this address. I have provided just an example. in my program I have used my original addresses

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security and disable 2 step verification and give a try.

Comment: I tried this way. also same thing happening. I cannot beleve what the error. I have tried a lot of tutorial. but same thing happened. how to solve this. this is the boring problem in my application. :(

Answer (score 0):

First, fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Next, use these [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post the debug output if you still can't figure it out.

You might want to surround your code with try/catch to make sure you're not missing an exception that's being thrown.

You don't say what application server you're using but if it's not a Java EE application server make sure the JavaMail jar file is in the server's "lib" directory or in the "lib" directory of your web application.